# Prevent unix tree from displaying back-slash before spaces

Tags: unix, command-line, command-line-interface

I use the command `tree` very often in command line (in *Mac*) and the tree structure of my current directory is listed as follows:

`└── A\ File\ with\ Space.mp4`

Is there an option to avoid displaying those back slashes?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

My `tree` command has a `-N` option to print non printable chars as is.

```
tree -N
.
├── a dirname with spaces
└── myscript.sh
```

Otherwise, you could use `printf` and `xargs`:

```
tree | xargs -L 1 -I xxxx printf "%s\n" xxxx
.
├── a dirname with spaces
└── myscript.sh
```

Special chars in names are going to break it or display surprising result: `\n` `'` `"` `*` etc.

Comment: Wow, I hadn't noticed this answer! I somehow didn't find this while skimming the man page. Anyways thanks pal! It was annoying to see the back slashes.